# HTTP Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Methods VS Allow

Tags: http, http-headers

What is the main difference between these two headers?

***Access-Control-Allow-Methods*** is located in headers collection of the request while ***Allow*** can be found inside of Content.Headers collection.

Which one I should care about while handling OPTIONS requests?

[image: postman-example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Allow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Allow) is a basic HTTP header which is used to describe which HTTP methods may be used to request a resource. This is in general and not specifically for JS. The header predates the existence of JS.

[`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) is a CORS extension to HTTP which describes which HTTP methods may be used by client-side code to make cross-origin requests to a resource.

---

You **must** include an `Allow` header if you are making a 405 response. You **may** always include it.

You **need** to include `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` if you are making a response to a preflight OPTIONS request (unless you don't want to use it to grant the follow-up request any permissions).

Comment: I see that many services do not return Allow header in 405 response.

Comment: @orzel — Then they are violating the HTTP spec.